# Free Multi-Monitor configuration switcher for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, multi-monitor

I have three monitors which I regularly use in two configurations:

- Duplicated Screen on A and B
- Extended Screen on B and C

Because I often switch between those two configurations, the manual setup via the Win 7 Screen Resolution dialog is costing me time.

I need a simple tool with the following features:

- Allows to save Multi-Monitor configurations for later reuse
- Allows to quickly switch between those pre-saved configurations
- Preferably: Allows to do the switching through hotkeys
- Works on Windows 7
- Free or very low one-time price (<10$/€)

DisplayFusion and UltraMon are good tools, but come with a plethora of features I don't need for a larger price than what I am looking for. I was hoping to find a free or cheap alternative that only does this one task (monitor switching) for me.

Comment: Not sure if the tag [tag:window-manager] is correct here. If not, please remove it.

Comment: Related (but different): [Program to save visible windows' locations and later restore of the layout](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1816/903)

Comment: Is a (PowerShell) script that does the job an acceptable solution?

Comment: As far as I can tell (without having 3 monitors to test this) you can use DisplaySwitch (Win7 onboard tool) for this. Like "DisplaySwitch /duplicate" should do the first, "DisplaySwitch /off /internal /extended" should do the other.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the current Catalyst Control Center has a function to switch between monitor configurations quickly through the Tray Menu. Works pretty well for me, but obviously this solution is limited to graphic cards from ATI.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clumsy workaround using [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) in case you did not find a direct answer. You can use a script to retrace the steps of manually switching the layouts. The sequance may differ from system to system so I will list the instructions along with a sample script that works on mine:

1. Open the **Screen Resolution** window, and press (on the keyboard) the number of the screen you'd like to edit. <kbd>2</kbd> for example
2. Count how many <kbd>Tab</kbd> presses it takes to reach the **Multiple Displays** menu. This number will change depending on the mode it's already in
3. Use the first letter of the menu entry to select it. <kbd>E</kbd> for **extend**, <kbd>D</kbd> for **duplicate**, etc...
4. Again count how many <kbd>Tab</kbd> presses it takes to reach the **OK** button

When you have all the variables, use them to modify the configuration section of this AutoHotKey script:

```
;; Configuration

myWinTitle := "Screen Resolution"      ;; Title of the window
dSequence := "2{Tab 4}d{Tab 6}{Enter}" ;; Key sequence for duplicating displays
eSequence := "2{Tab 2}e{Tab 8}{Enter}" ;; Key sequence for extending displays

;; End of configuration section

#NoEnv 
SendMode Input 
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#+d::
  Run control desk.cpl
  IfWinNotActive, %myWinTitle%, , WinActivate, %myWinTitle%, 
  WinWaitActive, %myWinTitle%,
  Send %dSequence%
  return

#+e::
  Run control desk.cpl
  IfWinNotActive, %myWinTitle%, , WinActivate, %myWinTitle%, 
  WinWaitActive, %myWinTitle%,
  Send %eSequence%
  return
```

The hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> should now switch to duplicate displays (by quickly retracing your steps), and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>  should swtich back to extended displays.

There are most likely cleaner ways to do this by directly editing the registery keys. I'll update the script if I figure it out.

Comment: Kudos for the work, but this is hardly an optimal solution. :)

Comment: @atticae I agree. It's more of a workaround than a solution, but it's better than having nothing. I'll happily delete it if a better answer is posted

Comment: No way, leave it there. If I ever change to a Nvidia card I might need it. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, definitely please don't delete it!