# Advanced window manager for Windows 10 to save size and position of each window

Tags: windows-10, window-manager

I use Windows 10 on desktop and I am looking for window manager doing one particular task: **save size and position** of each application window and restore them when the application is launched again. For instance, I sometimes change the size and position of my text editor, but I usually want it to open exactly on the same place and the same size that it had before last closing.

Snapping windows to a grid is nice to have, but not necessary. **AquaSnap is not an option**, because it can manipulate the existing windows but does not remember the position of closed ones.

Comment: FYI [Program to save visible windows' locations and later restore the layout](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1816/903)